# Is $f(x,y) = ( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2} )$ injective?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I came across this function in a context in which I need to know if it is injective. The function is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ and defined by $$f(x,y) = \Biggl( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2} \Biggl).$$

I guess it is injective. I have failed to find counterexamples, but I couldn't prove that it is injective. Maybe I should use some result, but I couldn't find any that seemed useful.

Hints or answers are much appreciated.

Comment: Change the $2y$ to $-y$ (which has no effect whether it is injective) and you have the map $z \mapsto 1/z$ on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @ErickWong: Nice observation.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments, they've helped my understanding of the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try solving $(u,v) = f(x,y)$. Here is a hint to start: Let $s = x^2+y^2$, this gives $u = \frac{x}{s}$, $\frac{v}{2} = \frac{y}{s}$. Squaring gives $u^2+(\frac{v}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{s}$, from which we get $s = \frac{1}{u^2+(\frac{v}{2})^2}$. Now figure out what $x,y$ are.

> Then  $x = s u$, $y = s \frac{v}{2}$ give $x = \frac{u}{u^2+(\frac{v}{2})^2}$, $y = \frac{\frac{v}{2}}{u^2+(\frac{v}{2})^2}$.

Since $f$ is invertible, it follows that it is injective.

Comment: How did you make the invisible box?

Comment: I used >! at the start. (You can edit my answer to look.)

Comment: Ah, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Express $x$ and $y$ from $u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v=\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$.

One more hint: for start, calculate $u^2+(v/2)^2$.